# How can I cancel the Window.ClosingEvent?

Tags: gwt, event-handling

I want to show a modal window (instead the confirm) when a user close the browser. The GWT documention remarks that (during the handler operation) no user UI may be displayed during the shutdown. Exists any way cancel the operation, from the client not from the user?

Thanks in advance,
Oscar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't cancel the close event. The best you can do is to let the user press cancel. I think the reason for this is to prevent "bad" javascript from not letting you close your browser.

This displays a dialog with a cancel option.

```
    Window.addWindowCloseListener(new WindowCloseListener()
    {
        public String onWindowClosing()
        {
            return "You are about to exit from the application. Are you sure?";
        }

        public void onWindowClosed()
        {
            //cleanup code  
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But I want to cancel the Close event to pass the control to other event. This event will display a custom windows to inform the user and after I will fire a Close event. The problem is that I don't know how to cancel the Close event. Thanks in advace!

Comment: You can't cancel the close event. The best you can do is to let the user press cancel. I think the reason for this is to prevent "bad" javascript from not letting you close your browser.

Comment: My problem is the client wants that the Comfirmation alert has the same style than the others modal windows in the application :-(

Comment: You'll have to tell your client that this is not technically possible.

Comment: Yes I will do but first I want to assure that is not possible in the way that he wants. Thanks in advance for everybody and Happy Xmas!